# SQL - third table joined to two tables but where condition of column in third table is different

Tags: sql

I need to join a table ('Project') to two other tables ('SalesOrder' and 'POI') on the same column name ('Project.PRJG_RecordID'), but a condition in the 'ProjectID' column in the 'Project' table must be null in 'POI' and not null in 'SalesOrder'.  How do you write that syntax?

The closest I've come is:

(EDITED SINCE ORIGINAL POST):

```
Select *
From SalesOrder
Inner Join Project On Project.PRJG_RecordID =
SalesOrder.SOM_PRJG_DfltRecordID
Left Join POI On ProjectGroup.PRJG_RecordID =
POI.POI_PRJG_DfltRecordID
Where Project.ProjectID is null -- as it relates to the POI table.
And Project.ProjectID = '12345' -- as it relates to the SalesOrder table.
```

NOTE: Project.PRJG_RecordID is a uniqueidentifier whereas Project.ProjectID is nvarchar(25).

How?

Comment: Bad query earlier; made edits.  Hopefully I made my question more easily understood above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear on what you want the output to look like, but try this. You need to make Project the left most because POI and SalesOrders both join to Project, but then you must filter out Project rows that don't join to at least one of the other 2 tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM Project
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrder On Project.PRJG_RecordID = SalesOrder.SOM_PRJG_DfltRecordID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN POI On Project.PRJG_RecordID = POI.POI_PRJG_DfltRecordID
WHERE (POI.POI_PRJG_DfltRecordID IS NOT NULL AND Project.ProjectID is null)
   OR (SalesOrder.SOM_PRJG_DfltRecordID IS NOT NULL AND Project.ProjectID is NOT null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but it seems like you would just need to add a

`AND SalesOrder.ProductID IS NOT NULL`

to the end of the WHERE clause

And you're also not joining the POI table. You join to ProjectGroup, which isn't used anywhere. Maybe you meant to do this?

```
Select *
From SalesOrder
Inner Join Project On Project.PRJG_RecordID =
SalesOrder.SOM_PRJG_DfltRecordID
Left Join POI On POI.POI_PRJG_DfltRecordID = SalesOrder.SOM_PRJG_DfltRecordID
Where Project.ProjectID is null
AND SalesOrder.ProductID IS NOT NULL
```